# Including multiple products in a single HTML table?

Tags: html, pdf

I have a problem with this HTML, as it creates different tables by grouping a product by name. For example: Product A and Product B. Product A appears in one table and Product B appears in another table, I would like to put it together so that it appears in one. the framework is odoo

**.xml**

```
<template id="inventario_report">

    <t t-call="web.html_container">

        <t t-call="web.internal_layout">

            <div class="article">

                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">

                    <table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;width:100%">

                        <th colspan="2" style="border:1px solid black;text-align:center"><span>Inventario</span></th>

                        <tbody>

                            <tr>

                                <td style="border:1px solid black;width:50%;text-align:center"><strong>Producto</strong></td>

                                <td style="border:1px solid black;width:50%;text-align:center"><strong>Stock</strong></td>

                            </tr>

                            <t t-foreach="doc.get('vals')" t-as="val">

                                <tr>

                                    <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('producto')"/></td>

                                    <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('stock')"/></td>

                                </tr>

                            </t>

                        </tbody>

                    </table>

                    <p></p>

                </t>

            </div>

        </t>

    </t>
```

**.py**

```
def get_values(self,star,end):

    docs = []

    product_ids = []

    detail =
```

self.env['proyecto_rc.detalle_documento'].search([('date','>=',star),('date','<=',end)])

```
    for de in detail:

        vals = {

            'product': de.product_id.name,

            'stock': de.product_id.stock,

        }

        if de.product_id.id in product_ids:

            pass

        else:

            product_ids.append(de.product_id.id)

            docs.append({

                'product': de.product_id.name,

                'vals': [vals],

            })

    return docs
```

[image]

Comment: What technology is this exactly?

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Que programa o framework está interpretando esta línea? `t-foreach="doc.get('vals')"` (No es html solamente)

Comment: I am working with Odoo, do I include the method?

Comment: Edit your question to add that information (that you are working with Odoo, otherwise nobody knows) And if the method matters then yes

Comment: there I added the part of the method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy to see why your implementation fails to achieve what you expected.

First, notice that in the template you loop over the `docs` list, so that each element in the `docs` list will generate an additional table (with header):

```
<t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
  <table style="border:1px solid b....
```

Then, inside that table, you create an additional row for each element of the `vals` list inside of the element in the `docs` list over which you are looping.

```
<t t-foreach="doc.get('vals')" t-as="val">
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('producto')"/></td>
    <td style="text-align:center"><t t-esc="val.get('stock')"/></td>
  </tr>
</t>
```

However, on the python script:

```
for de in detail:
   ...
        docs.append({
            'product': de.product_id.name,
            'vals': [vals],
        })
```

You are appending a new element to the `docs` table for each item in `detail`, therefore creating a new table on the template.

Instead, append to vals, not to docs:

```
def get_values(self, star, end):

    docs = []
    product_ids = []
    detail = ... # However you get your document

    vals = [] # Create the list of values of the document

    for de in detail:

        if de.product_id.id in product_ids:
            pass

         else:
            product_ids.append(de.product_id.id)

            vals.append({
                'product': de.product_id.name,
                'stock': de.product_id.stock,
            })

    docs.append(vals)
```

The final product should look like this:
If we had two documents, one for fruits and the other listing office supplies,

```
docs = [[{'product': 'bananas', 'stock', 1}, {'product': 'apples', 'stock', 1}], [{'product': 'staples', 'stock', 1}, {'product': 'paper', 'stock', 1}]]
```

Should you want to access multiple documents, just wrap the loop in another loop, changing the document each time

EDIT: You will have to change this line

```
<t t-foreach="doc.get('vals')" t-as="val">
```

to this

```
<t t-foreach="doc" t-as="val">
```

Comment: make the changes you told me but I get the following error: NameError: name 'docs' is undefined

Comment: I edited my answer to include the beginning of the code. Make sure you have the line `docs = []`

Comment: if I add the docs = [] but the report is blank, the whole sheet is blank

Comment: Just copy my edited answer. Sounds like you added the line after everything. You are supposed to add it before, before vals = [] for example.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong but I am attaching an image of how I currently have the code so you can see if I wrote something wrong. link: https://ibb.co/cCJbL9T

Comment: you mistyped 'de.product_id' as 'de.producto_id' in line 61.

Comment: already worked, it was a database error. Thank you very much to all.